# Combine Moment.js functionality with jQuery function that parses XML document

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing, momentjs

I'm trying to use Moment.js with a jQuery function that parses an XML document.  The original function just parsed the XML doc targeting an "asofdate" element and the "acronym" element to display a link to a PDF file.

Now, after the document is parsed, I'm trying to target the XML element, "asofdate", using Moment.js and convert the date from numeric to text.

Could anyone possibly guide me in the right direction?  It continues to display the date in numeric format.  Using Moment.js on it's own works great.  I just need to combine the two if possible.

XML code, file name: content.xml

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252" standalone="no"?>
 <presentvalue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <rundate>2015-04-30</rundate>
 <asofdate>2015-03-31</asofdate>
 <data>
 <report>
 <acronym>abb1gx</acronym>
 <fundname>Balanced Growth Composite</fundname>
 </report>
 </data>
 </presentvalue>`
```

HMTL, jQuery, and Moment.js

```
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="moment-develop/moment.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        moment().format();
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

    function parse(document) {

        $(document).find("presentvalue").each(function(){
            $("#date").append(
                ''+$(this).find('asofdate').text()+
                ''
            );  
        })

        $(document).find("report").each(function(){

            var x = $(this).find('acronym').text();
            //alert("x::"+x
            //);   
            var returnedURL = url(x);
            //alert("returnedURL:11:"+returnedURL); 
            $("#content").append(
                <!--
                //''+$(this).find('acronym').text()+
                // add closing tag back here
                '<a href=" ' +returnedURL + '" target="_blank">' + $(this).find('fundname').text() + '</a>' +
                //'<br />URL: <a href="'+returnedURL+'" target="_blank">' +returnedURL+'</a>'+
                '</p>'
            );
        });
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: 'reports.xml', // name of file you want to parse
        dataType: "xml",
        success: parse,
        error: function() {
            alert("Error: Something went wrong");
        }
    });
    // function will loop through all tags and create 
    // url string  
    function url(acroynm) {  
        //alert("acroynm in url()::"+acroynm);   
        var parsedUrl;
        var counter = 0; // counter for funds         
        i = 0; // loop variable         
        // final url string
        parsedUrl = 'http://www.testsite/files/';               
        //alert("url:11:"+url); 
        parsedUrl = parsedUrl + acroynm + ".pdf";    
        //alert("parsedUrl:22:"+parsedUrl); 
        return parsedUrl;

    }

    (function() {           
        alert('render date as text');   
        var correct = document.getElementById('date').innerHTML;            
        var Date1 = moment(correct, 'YYYY-MM-DD');

        document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = Date1.format('MMMM DD, YYYY');

    })();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <center>
            <p><b>Data As Of:<div id="date"></div></b></p>
        </center>
        <div id="content">
        </div><!-- end content-->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container --> 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I've almost got this working.  I added a function to also target the "rundate" element in the XML which now shows up in the HTML as the content id "rdate."

Comment: Now, before the Moment.js kicks in, I added an alert. You can click OK on the alert and the date now successfully converts.  However, if i remove the alert it breaks and displays the "invalid date" error with teh date in numeric data next to it.  Here's my updated code.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I've updated the HMTL, jQuery, and Moment.js code above in original post to reflect my changes.  Again, it works until I remove the alert

Comment: I found there was no need to target the "rundate" element in the XML, so I removed that content id from the HTML.  In the Moment.js function I set both getElementByIds to target the "date" id in the HTML.  This cleaned up the code a bit by removing an unnecessary function, but the problem persists: it works fine if I leave the alert in, but removing returns an invalid date with the numeric date alongside. I'm still working at this, but any help/insight as to why removing the alert is breaking it would be extremely grateful. Updated code is above.